# How to verify the SSL certificate of a node in the (GUI) wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, remote-node, connection

I'm connecting to a remote node that uses SSL. The node uses a self-signed certificate. When connecting, the GUI wallet didn't ask me to accept the certificate nor can I find any way to check and verify certificate.

1. How can I prevent the wallet from connecting to a node before the certificate has been verified in some way?
2. How can I check and accept/deny certificates of remote nodes in the wallet?
3. If the node uses CA-signed certificate (e.g., Let's Encrypt), can the wallet then trust the certificate automatically?

In my opinion, this is very important because otherwise I will always have to treat the connection even to a trusted node as if there was a man in the middle. So, without a secure connection, one can't really trust the node either as far as I understand.